input variable fails to get applied during the cdktf synth execution
Here is info about our technical development environment :

HashiCorp.Cdktf 0.16.3
HashiCorp.Cdktf.Providers.Aws 14.0.4
HashiCorp.Cdktf.Providers.Docker 7.0.1
Amazon.Lambda.Core 2.1.0
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson 2.3.1
Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents 2.6.0

The AWS Lambda project contains the following:

Amazon.Lambda.Core 2.1.0
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson 2.3.1
Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents 2.6.0


cdktf debug
language: csharp
cdktf-cli: 0.20.6
node: v18.20.1
cdktf: 0.20.6
constructs: 10.3.0
jsii: 1.96.0
terraform: 1.5.7
arch: x64
os: win32 10.0.22631
dotnet: 8.0.202
providers
HashiCorp.Cdktf.Providers.Aws (PREBUILT)
    terraform provider version: 5.44.0

    prebuilt provider version: 19.13.0

    cdktf version: ^0.20.0 HashiCorp.Cdktf.Providers.Docker (PREBUILT)

    terraform provider version: 3.0.2

    prebuilt provider version: 11.0.0

    cdktf version: ^0.20.0 P


I am trying to use Terraform CDKTF tool to deploy a C#-based AWS Lambda to Amazon AWS Cloud.
In my Visual Studio 2022 Solution, I have the following projects:

AWSSrvlessHelloWorldApp
AWSSrvlessHelloWorldApp.Tests
MyTerraformStack

I build the AWSSrvlessHelloWorldApp Lambda Project.
I wanted to supply argument parameters when I run cdktf deploy
Therefore, as I researched, I came across the following webpage link that describes how to use Terraform variables as input parameters:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/variables-and-outputs
Here is an excerpt from the aforementioned webpage that shows sample declaration & instantiation of Terraform variables as input parameters in C#:
I build the AWSSrvlessHelloWorldApp Lambda Project.
I wanted to supply argument parameters when I run cdktf deploy
Therefore, as I researched, I came across the following webpage link that describes how to use Terraform variables as input parameters:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/variables-and-outputs
Here is an excerpt from the aforementioned webpage that shows sample declaration & instantiation of Terraform variables as input parameters in C#:
TerraformVariable imageId = new TerraformVariable(this, "imageId",
    new TerraformVariableConfig
    {
        Type = "string",
        Default = "ami-abcde123",
        Description = "What AMI to use to create an instance",
    });

new Instance(this, "hello", new InstanceConfig
    {
        Ami = imageId.StringValue,
        InstanceType = "t2.micro",
    });

In the MyTerraformStack ( i.e. the TerraformStack Project) I have the following files:

Program.cs
MainStack.cs

In Program.cs , I have the following code( Please note that I use Debugger.Launch() so that I can bring up the MyTerraformStack in Visual Studio 2022 whenever I run cdktf from Powershell commandline ) :
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        App app = new App();
        MainStack stack = new MainStack(app, "aws_instance");
        app.Synth();
    }
}

In MainStack.cs, the code content’s are:
class MainStack : TerraformStack
{
    public MainStack(Construct scope, string id) : base(scope, id)
    {
        TerraformVariable imageId = new TerraformVariable(this, "imageId", new
        TerraformVariableConfig
        {
        Type = "string",
        Default = "ami-abcde123",
        Description = "What AMI to use to create an instance",
        });

        new Instance(this, "hello", new InstanceConfig
        {
        Ami = imageId.StringValue,
        InstanceType = "t2.micro",
        });

        Console.Error.WriteLine("imageId.ToString()");
        Console.Error.WriteLine(imageId.ToString());

        Console.Error.WriteLine("imageId.StringValue");
        Console.Error.WriteLine(imageId.StringValue);

        ...Blah Blah configuring ITerraformAssetConfig and

        IS3BucketObjectConfig and IIamRoleConfig

        Blah Blah...

        ...Blah Blah instantiating S3BucketObject , IamRole ,

        LambdaFunction Blah Blah Blah

    } 
}

In Windows Powershell, I've run the following:

$Env:TF_VAR_imageId="testing"
cdktf synth

However, when I Console Writeline code gets executes, I gives the following output:

imageId.ToString()
[2024-04-08T14:59:56.904] [ERROR] default - ${TfToken[TOKEN.1]}
imageId.StringValue
[2024-04-08T14:59:56.904] [ERROR] default - ${TfToken[TOKEN.2]}

The imageId's value fails to get applied during the cdktf synth execution.
Why, and could someone please tell me how to resolve said problem?

LOL you stackoverflow folks are all slacking. :)
I got the following solution from someone on reddit
In my C# Terraform CDKTF application, I have the following snippet of code:

TerraformVariable imageId = new TerraformVariable(this, "imageId", new
TerraformVariableConfig
{
Type = "string",
Default = "ami-abcde123",
Description = "What AMI to use to create an instance",
});
Console.Error.WriteLine("****************************************");
Console.Error.WriteLine("****************************************");
Console.Error.WriteLine("imageId.StringValue");
Console.Error.WriteLine(imageId.StringValue);
Console.Error.WriteLine("imageId.Value.ToString()");
Console.Error.WriteLine(imageId.Value.ToString());
Console.Error.WriteLine("****************************************");
Console.Error.WriteLine("****************************************");
TerraformOutput outputVar = new TerraformOutput(this, "outputVar", new
TerraformOutputConfig
{
Value = imageId.StringValue,
});
Console.Error.WriteLine("****************************************");
Console.Error.WriteLine("****************************************");
Console.Error.WriteLine("outputVar.Value");
Console.Error.WriteLine(outputVar.Value);

I have a file called inputfile.tfvars that will be processed as input, and it contains:

imageId = "testing"

after running the following commands in order, it worked:

cdktf synth
cdktf deploy -var-file="inputfile.tfvars"

